# Emacs : Search and replace operations

Tags: regex, emacs, operation

I'm looking for a way to search and replace regexp with Emacs while also doing operations. I don't really know how to explain it but here is an example :

Let's say I have this code going on for 200+ lines :

```
"lq.u $r40r41 = 0[$r39]\n"
"addd $r14r15 = $r14$r15, $r40$r41\n"
";;\n"              
"lq.u $r42r43 = 16[$r39]\n"             
"addd $r16r17 = $r16$r17, $r42$r43\n"
";;\n"
```

And I made a mistake in the choice of my registers so I want to change them into :

```
"load $r39r40 = 0[$r39]\n"
"add $r13r14 = $r13$r14, $r39$r40\n"
";;\n"              
"load $r41r42 = 16[$r39]\n"             
"addd $r15r16 = $r15$r16, $r41$r42\n"
";;\n"
```

So basically, what I would like would be a way to regexp search 2 digit numbers "XX" and replace them by "XX-1". Is there a way to do this through Emacs or else ?

I managed to save some time from manual editing using Excel sheets but I need a more efficient and less dummy way of doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell whether there should always be a `$` before the `r`, so either:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `query-replace-regexp` <kbd>RET</kbd> `\$r\([0-9]+\)` <kbd>RET</kbd> `$r\,(1- \#1)` <kbd>RET</kbd>

or:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `query-replace-regexp` <kbd>RET</kbd> `r\([0-9]+\)` <kbd>RET</kbd> `r\,(1- \#1)` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Where:

- `\,` evaluates a lisp expression in the replacement, and hence:
- `\,(1- ...)` is a call to the `1-` function, with the argument:
- `\#1` which, within this replacement syntax, represents group 1 of the match as a number.

Comment: Thanks, could you explain what you are doing there ? I don't understand this part of the regex  :   r\,(1- \#1)

Comment: See the Emacs manual, node [Regexp Replace](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Replace.html). Maybe @phils will want to add some explanation about this.